# Testing login system on local server

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, authentication

I'm using a codeigniter library called tankauth. It creates a user table in the db with sessions and encrypted password. When registering users they have to check their email and confirm registration. For testing locally can I just manually add data to the table?

I'm not sure if sessions work locally as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions work locally because the user end is kept as a sort of cookie and the server end is kept by your local web server. You could enter data manually, or you could use multiple users/browsers on your computer to test.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a mail server locally, e.g [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) or [Mercury Mail Transport System](http://www.pmail.com/) for MS-Windows. That way you can test if the registration works correctly.